# php $_SERVER['argv'][0] error in osCommerce

Tags: php, oscommerce

I am running an osCommerce app on GoDaddy.(I'm not a php expert though)
I recently found that some admin pages give errors.
I narrowed the problem down to the following line.

```
$pIDlist_array=split("&", $_SERVER["argv"][0]);
```

`$_SERVER["argv"][0]` returns always `NULL`.

I think it's because register_argc_argv is off in global php configuration.

I created php.ini in the web root directory and the file has `register_argc_argv = on`.
But it doesn't seem to override the default option.

My questions are:

1. Can I override `register_argc_argv` in my php.ini on GoDaddy? Do you have experience with GoDaddy?
2. If I can't change `register_argc_argv` option, what can I do?
3. I want to avoid modify all source codes. But if that's the only option, how should I change the problem line?

Thanks.

Sam

Comment: What version of osCommerce are you running?

Answer (score 1):

> From GoDaddy’s support:
>
> ```
> Thank you for contacting Online Support.
>
> Unfortunately, register_argc_argv is not available in our shared hosting
> accounts and we cannot activate for you. We apologize for any
> inconvenience this may cause.
>
> Please let us know if there is anything further that we can do for
> ```
>
> you.
>       Our service departments and telephone lines are open 24 hours a
>   day, 365
>       days a year to accommodate your needs anytime.

[Found Here](http://www.thewebhostinghero.com/tutorials/godaddy-openx-issue.html)

Comment: When I work on sites hosted on GoDaddy, I have found that's the answer to almost every PHP feature I asked them about. Avoid GoDaddy hosting!